# Show the name of state variables from useState in React Developer Tool

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning [react-hooks](/questions/tagged/react-hooks), I created a series of state variables using `useState`, when trying to debug and see its value I find that React Developer Tool does not show the name assigned to the state variable but the text State, this is inconvenient as it is not possible to identify from the beginning which variable is the one that is tried to debug

[image]

**Update 1**

This is the current source code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";

function Main() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("redux");
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(
    "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux"
  );
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();

        setData(json);
      } catch (e) {
        setIsError(true);
      }

      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form
        onSubmit={event => {
          setUrl(`http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=${query}`);
          event.preventDefault();
        }}
      >
        <input value={query} onChange={event => setQuery(event.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>

      {isError && <div>Something went wrong ...</div>}

      {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {data.hits.map(item => (
            <li key={item.objectID}>
              <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

I am getting this in React Developer tool

[image]

**Updated 2**

I am using Firefox 68

Is it possible that React Developer Tool shows the name of state variables created using `useState`?

Comment: can you please share your source code here?

Comment: you supposed to see something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTy3b.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See this issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/1215#issuecomment-479937560

That's the normal behavior for the dev tool when using hooks.

I asked the library author about it, cause I also would like it to show my state variable names. And that's what he said:

> @cbdeveloper I haven't thought of a good way for DevTools to be able to display the variable name like you're asking. **DevTools doesn't have a way to read your function's private variables,** and changing the API to support passing in a display name would increase the size of component code. It also just doesn't seem necessary to me, more like a nice to have.
>
> Anyway, this umbrella issue is not the best place to have discussions like this. If you feel strongly about it, I suggest opening a new issue.

Answer (score 8):

From "normal" `useState hook` implementation:

```
const [users, setUser] = useState([]);
const [profile, setProfile] = useState([]);
const [repo, setRepo] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false);
```

You can "convert" it in:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ users: [], profile: [], repo: [], loading: false, alert: false });
```

And you will get the following result:

[image]

And to `set the state` you can use the `rest operator`([source 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) / [source 2](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/javascripts-three-dots-spread-vs-rest-operators543)) and the `state` you want to set:

```
// ...state => unchanged states
// alert => state we want to change
setState(state => ({ ...state, alert: true }));
```

to use it as a `prop`:

```
const {
 users,
 profile,
 repo,
 loading,
 alert
} = state;

<SomeComponent loading={loading} alert={alert} />
```

You see the `React docs` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html) and search for: `Should I use one or many state variables?`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`useDebugValue`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usedebugvalue) to display a custom label in your own hook:

```
const format = ({ label, value }) =>
  label + ': ' + (typeof value === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(value) : value);

const useNamedState = (label, initialState) => {
  const states = useState(initialState);
  useDebugValue({ label, value: states[0] }, format);
  return states;
};
```

### Usage

###### Before

```
const [name, setName] = useState('bob');
const [age, setAge] = useState(11);
const [address, setAddress] = useState('London, United Kingdom');
const [isVirgin, setIsVirgin] = useState(false);
const [isMale, setIsMale] = useState(true);
const [hobbies, setHobbies] = useState(['gaming', 'hiking', 'cooking']);
const [friendList, setFriendList] = useState(['bob']);
```

[image]

###### After

```
const [name, setName] = useNamedState('name', 'bob');
const [age, setAge] = useNamedState('age', 11);
const [address, setAddress] = useNamedState('address', 'London, United Kingdom');
const [isVirgin, setIsVirgin] = useNamedState('isVirgin', false);
const [isMale, setIsMale] = useNamedState('isMale', true);
const [hobbies, setHobbies] = useNamedState('hobbies', ['gaming', 'hiking', 'cooking']);
const [friendList, setFriendList] = useNamedState('friendList', ['bob']);
```

[image]

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not sure why it doesn't show the names, but if I'm trying to create a series of state variables, I sometimes just initialize a state and setState variable as an empty object. I'm not sure if this is the best way, but maybe in your dev tools, it'll show the state attribute name when you expand it.

```js
import React from "react";

export default function App(props) {
  // Initializing the state
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({});
  
  // Changing the state
  setState({ ...state, text1: "hello world", text2: "foobar" });
  
  return (
    <div>
      {state.text1}
      <br />
      {state.text2}
    </div>
  );
}
```